# Open Graph Object Debugger finds nothing for my URL. Why?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Help! This doesn't make sense. At https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object/, I fetch for http://mycommunity.org, and Facebook gives me these errors:

```
Object at URL 'http://mycommunity.org/' of type 'website' is invalid because a required property 'og:title' of type 'string' was not provided.
Curl Error : RECV_ERROR Recv failure: Connection reset by peer
```

I've verified my server returns a 200. I've verified the og tags are correct. I'm not sure why Facebook would get "Connection reset by peer".

When I click "See exactly what our scraper sees for your URL", I get nothing:

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/echo?q=http%3A%2F%2Fmycommunity.org%2F

What gives? Thank you!

Comment: Did you find the problem? I got the same issue with one of my websites.

Comment: I have exactly the same problem.